# How to access more complex nested data JSON in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, multidimensional-array, nested-object

I'm trying to render a row of 10 books and a row of 10 movies from my component which would look like rows in netflix to give you an idea. I've shortened the json bellow. I'm able to fetch and access my data and save it in useState of the component. Although I'm not able to render. Lack of experience. I've paste result in both console.log bellow react component. Help would be welcome please!!!

JSON file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "rowTitle": "Books",
    "row": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Book1",
        "desc": "Book1 description",
        "url": "images/books/Book1.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Book2",
        "desc": "Book2 description",
        "url": "images/books/Book2.jpeg"
      },
  
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rowTitle": "Movies",
    "row": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "movie1",
        "desc": "movie1 description",
        "url": "images/movies/movie1.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "movie2",
        "desc": "movie2 description",
        "url": "images/movies/movie2.jpeg"
      },

    ]
  }
]
```

React component

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Caroussel, RowSlider, SliderContainer, Title } from './Home.styled';

import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('data/projects.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((myJson) => {
        console.log(myJson);
        setData(myJson);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    // lazyLoad: 'progressive',
  };

  return (
    <>
      <RowSlider>
        <Title>
          {data.map((obj) => {
            console.log(obj);
            // RESULT -> Object { id: 1, rowTitle: "Books", row: (10) […] }
            return <h1>{obj.rowTitle}</h1>; 
// -> RESULT but this render at the same time both titles (BOOKS and MOVIES), and I need to render BOOKS title first then its books row before rendering next row, MOVIES title and its movies..
          })}
        </Title>
        <SliderContainer>
          <Caroussel {...settings}>
            {data &&
              data.map((slide) => {
                console.log(slide);
                // RESULT -> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. ** BUT not event sure event if they was an it would still be working
                return (
                  <div key={slide.id}>
                    <div className="slick-slide">
                      <img
                        className="slick-slide-image"
                        alt={slide.title}
                        src={slide.url}
                      />

                      <h2 className="slick-slide-title">{slide.title}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/stations">
                      <div className="slick-slide-filter"> </div>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </Caroussel>
        </SliderContainer>
      </RowSlider>
    </>
  );
};
//  {/* <label className="slick-slide-label">{slide.label}</label> */}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Your data is an array of objects which contains a property called "row" which is also an array. You're not iterating over the row property.

Comment: @Andy, yes but I just do not know how to do this. It's been hours now :(

Comment: just make another .map

Comment: @Andy Gave me the same error, Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Also, what about the first console.log for the Title, should ti render both titles first or one title, then books before rendering the other title movies?

Comment: @War10ck wrote an answer which fixed it!! but his answer disappeared for some reasons. I've been in this for hours and just cannot thank you enough! Very,  appreciated to all of you for your time :))

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an array of objects so you a) need to iterate ([`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) over them, and then b) `map` over the row array inside those objects to build the HTML.

```js
function Example({ data }) {

  function getJSX(data) {

    // `map` over the array and for each object
    // return the rowTitle, and also `map` over
    // each object in `row` and return some markup
    return data.map(obj => {
      return (
        <div key={obj.id}>
          <h4>{obj.rowTitle}</h4>
          {obj.row.map(row => {
            return <div>{row.title}: {row.desc}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {getJSX(data)}
    </div>
  );

};

const data=[{id:1,rowTitle:"Books",row:[{id:1,title:"Book1",desc:"Book1 description",url:"images/books/Book1.jpeg"},{id:2,title:"Book2",desc:"Book2 description",url:"images/books/Book2.jpeg"}]},{id:2,rowTitle:"Movies",row:[{id:1,title:"movie1",desc:"movie1 description",url:"images/movies/movie1.jpeg"},{id:2,title:"movie2",desc:"movie2 description",url:"images/movies/movie2.jpeg"}]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```